# How to get the data inside a structure block

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I would like to get block data from structure blocks, in the same way if you would the following command:

`/data get block 1 2 3`
which gives `1, 2, 3 has the following block data: {metadata: "abc", mirror: "NONE", ignoreEntities: 1b, powered: 0b, seed: 0:, author: "myplayername", rotation:"NONE", posX: 0, mode: "DATA", posY: 1, sizeX: 0, posZ: 0, integrity: 1.0f, showair: 0b, x: 1, name:"", y: 2, z:3, id: "minecraft:structure_block", sizeY: 0, sizeZ: 0, showboundingbox: 1b}`

Specifically I need the data in "metadata", ie the stuff you find if you just enter into "Custom Data Tag Name". I have tried `block.getBlockData()`, `block.getMetadata("")`, `block.getMetadata(null)` and `block.getData()`. Scouring the bukkit and spigot docs and help threads for a while yielded the examples I have just tried, and pretty much everywhere else I looked had no related help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out you need to cast the `Block` type to the `Structure` type to get more info about the structure block that the basic `block.getType()` etc can't provide.

To get the raw string of structure block metadata (which is different to block metadata, for example this metadata remains after a server restart) do:

Structure structure_block = (Structure) block.getState();
String metadata_string = structure_block.getMetadata();

and to check that you've got it all right:

```
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.block.BlockBreakEvent;

import org.bukkit.block.Structure;   //this bit is required to implement the solution above

@EventHandler
public void onBlockBreak(BlockBreakEvent event) {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if(block.getType() == Material.STRUCTURE_BLOCK) {               //just make sure it is a structure block before trying to cast types
        event.setCancelled(true);                                   //this makes the block not break when you punch it
        Structure structure_block = (Structure) block.getState();   //this bit is the important casting operation
        player.sendMessage(structure_block.getMetadata());          //send the raw string data to the player directly
    }
}
```

This code contains a whole copy-pasteable implementation (hopefully), but the important bits relevant to the answer are commented as such.

Answer (score 0):

it seems all the stuff that is stored in the Metadata is just accesible, e.g. like so:

```java
block.getBiome();
block.getLocation();
block.getType();
```

What exactly do you want to do with the metadata?

Also beware that the metadata is deleted every time the server restart's so it's not really a viable source of information , except you know for sure, that it contains proper data, e.g. if you get your block from a `BlockPlaceEvent` or something.

Comment: What I specifically wanted was the text inside a structure block in "custom data tag mode", this isn't in block data unlike the stuff you mentioned there (minor edit: as far as I know, I may have overlooked it somehow). My intention was to use the "custom data tag mode" as a text entry for a player.

Comment: So if you had just overlooked it, have you solved your problem? ^^

Comment: I checked the docs and my IDE autocomplete options, and nothing there works for me. However, in the process I did find the answer which I shall put in an answer to the original question.